Is there any algorithm to check memory safety and data races at the same time?
I am aware of the question regarding combining AddressSanitizer and ThreadSanitizer. I am asking about this from the theoretical computer science point of view, prompted by an earlier discussion.
Consider the following buggy C++ program:
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

static std::mutex m;
static char *buf;

static void a()
{
  for (;;) {
    char *b;
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g{m};
      b = buf;
    }
    if (b)
      puts(b);
  }
}

static void b()
{
  for (;;) {
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g{m};
      buf = strdup("foo");
    }

    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g{m};
      buf = static_cast<char*>(realloc(buf, 10000));
      strcpy(buf, "barbarbar");
    }

    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g{m};
      free(buf);
      buf = nullptr;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  auto thread_a = std::thread(a);
  auto thread_b = std::thread(b);
  thread_a.join();
  // unreachable
  thread_b.join();
  return 0;
}

When compiled with GCC 14.2.0 or Clang 20 using -fsanitize=address, the program will terminate instantly with a heap-use-after-free error, because a() is using a stale copy of a pointer.
When compiled without special options and run with valgrind ./a.out, on my system the program would run for nearly 4 minutes before reporting the first Invalid read of size 1. This I assume is because Valgrind is emulating multiple threads by preemptive scheduling in a single thread, and therefore you would need some luck to get a context switch between a() and b() at the right moment for the error to be reproduced.
Similarly, when the program is compiled with GCC or Clang using -fsanitize=thread, it seems to keep running without any problem.
My question: Has there been any recent academic research that would improve upon the ThreadSanitizer algorithm in this respect?

Are you asking a theoretical computer science question or a practical one ? Theoretically it cannot be done in general. In practice there are heuristics to catch common cases, and these heuristics keep getting better (although they will never work 100% due to the theortical limitation).

I could be wrong, but I bet the reason why ASAN and TSAN can't be used together isn't some fundamental limitation of computers or of our universe (that theoretical computer science would deal with), but simply that nobody bothered to fix the compatibility. In practice, you'd just run your test suite twice, with ASAN and with TSAN separately.

ASAN instrumentation and TSAN instrumentation don't play nice together.  Needs unification.  Unifying them is left as an exercise for the reader.  (If you do unify them, please submit a pull request so others can enjoy the benefits.)

The pragmatic answer as of today indeed is to compile and test the source code with all of ASAN (+ UBSAN) and TSAN and MSAN separately.
A practical answer could be to implement some heuristic, possibly guided by some additional instrumentation, say, "this pointer is not safe to dereference after releasing the mutex". (That would not be a universal rule for all mutex-protected pointers.)

Valgrind memcheck, DRD and Helgrind all detect errors in this code.
For DRD I recommend using --tool=drd --fair-sched=yes --check-stack-var=yes.
For Helgrind I recommend using --tool=helgrind --fair-sched=yes.
And for memcheck just --fair-sched=yes.
Without fair scheduling it takes a bit longer to trigger the errors in my tests, sometimes 10 seconds whilst fair scheduling is generally within a few seconds.
Fair scheduling is only available on Linux. Porting it to FreeBSD is on my todo list.
Only one build required, and I only used GCC.
